# Only one streaming result set may be open and in use per-connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active result

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, datagrip, heidisql

I have a problem executing a **stored procedure(routine) from MySQL**. With clients like **HeidiSQL, DataGrip** and others it doesn't work at all, but with **MySQL Workbench** it works. Where is the problem? I connect to a MySQL server from another computer.

With other MySQL clients that are not Workbench:

With MySQL Workbench:
[image: workbench img]

Comment: This is JDBC driver's bug, you should report it to MySQL.

Comment: The error was corrected thank you very much!!. Basically it was because it returned two results. The first was a "select" string without executing and the second the result itself.

Comment: So, MySQL fixed this?

Comment: I was getting this on Intellij, after updating MySql Connector containing `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` class to version `8.0.21` it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

With other MySQL clients other than Workbench:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsVRN.png)